# Running ubuntu server behind a router DSL-2780

Tags: networking, server, ssh, router, port-forwarding

I am not sure if this qualifies as an Ubuntu related question or if i need to go to a D-Link related community.

I am currently following the [ars technica guide on setting up a home server](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2012/11/how-to-set-up-a-safe-and-secure-web-server/3/) using an HP Proliant G7 i have just got running here.

It is running a fresh Ubuntu server install 12.04.03 LTS.

I have additionally purchased a domain, and having tweaked and fiddled with SSL keys and certs am ready to "Expose it to the big bad internet".

A little stuck on how though...

My network setup is a bit heath Robinson with a D-Link DSL-2780 as the main router with an additional TP-Link WR841N as a switch (DHCP off).

- Can I run my server behind this setup, or will I need to flash my DD-Wrt (which is [appearing to be a minor headache](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=74112&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=450&sid=d5b8dcec29da5fe8555073e9b26876fa))
- Am I correct in thinking I will need to port forward (same as what D-Link calls virtual server?)
- If so, assuming [this guide applies](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Dlink/DSL-2780/XBOX360_Need_for_Speed_-_The_Run.htm), I will need to work out what goes where here... I'm thinking

  Enable Virtual Server Rules : [tick]
  Name : [insert name for my reference only]
  Interface : [PVC0 (only choice)]
  Internal IP : [The static LAN IP address of my server]
  Internal startport : (?)
  Internal endport :   (?)
  External endport :   (?)
  External endport :   (?)
  Protocol : [TCP / UDP / Both (?)]

I had hoped to forward for a key secured SSH (22), HTTP (80) and HTTPS (433), I imagine i would need to create a rule for each... just not sure now if there's a different 433 port for internal / external and where they start and end!

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution on  [on Portforward.com](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Dlink/DSL-2780/SSH.htm)

I will repost here just in-case anyone has a problem in future:

- On a D-Link DSL-2780 go into the main settings panel (often either via 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.0.1 and log in via the admin password).
- Go to **Advance** on the top menu bar then **Virtual Server** on the left menu bar.
- This page controls port forwarding, there should be a number of pre-existing rules below (mine had xbox ports active for some reason but also presets for FTP, HTTP, HTTPS etc). Create a new rule by filling in the settings below: I've explained what each do because this is where I got stuck!

> Enable Virtual Server Rules : [Click to enable the rule]
>
> Name : [insert name for your reference so you can find it later]
>
> Interface : [PVC0 (only choice)]
>
> Internal IP : [Choose the IP of your server on the LAN network (ie. usually 192.168.x.xx) Helps if you've made this a static local IP elsewhere in the router settings]

So far as I can tell the router will act like points on a traintrack, allowing it to listen to an 'external port range' and then send it to your server on an different 'internal port range'. Thus you'll want to match the internal setting to what you've set your router to listen and send via and your external one to how you want to display / hide the port to the rest of the world.

> Internal startport : [The beginning of the range that your home server will listen on- for a single port use the same number for both!]
>
> Internal endport : [The end of the range that your home server will listen on- for a single port use the same number for both!]
>
> External startport : [The beginning of the range that your router will listen on- for a single port use the same number for both!]
>
> External endport : [The end of the range that your router will listen on- for a single port use the same number for both!]
>
> Protocol : [TCP / UDP / Both Depending on what application you need to use, choose one!]

The settings below beginning with a time: enable / disable radio button can make the rule automatically turn on and off on a certain schedule. I believe you could use to to say... only allow the SSH port at a time when you know you'll want to use it!

Seems simple on reflection, hope that helps someone else at some point.

Comment: Ok... think it worked... not sure how to check. If someone could suggest I'll post a visual guide of steps for any others!